# How to copy Database from existing to new database sql script using sql server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i need sql script for copy database with data in sql server 2008 r2.I tried the below script but not working in sql server 2008.

```
DBCC CLONEDATABASE ('MyDatabase', 'MyDatabase_Copy')
```

Comment: you cannot do a backup and restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a copy of the full database to another one you can make a full backup of the existing one and restore it as another database.

To perform a [backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql) you can do doing something like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK='C:\Backup directory\MyDatabase.bak'
  WITH INIT, FORMAT, SKIP
```

Then you [restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) that backup in the destination database (either overwriting an existing database or creating a new one):

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase_Copy FROM DISK='C:\Backup directory\MyDatabase.bak'
  WITH REPLACE
```

If the destination database already exists you could need to use the `MOVE` option in the restore step (or perform a `DROP DATABASE MyDatabase_Copy` before restoring).